# PHP DOM XML read preferably with xPath

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have this xml

```
<App>
<Id id="129"/>
<Path id="category/self"/>
<Screenshots>
    <Screenshot url="small_480x320_34eaefb6c934a0d82da637bec2276bdd_ebecfca09179d055ed4d3cf15a41bf7c-8f95512356608b888f288b374db7b37fabb3ce27.jpg"/>
    <Screenshot url="small_480x320_438a9e1352bda4ef9724ae422473a556_615625ab835b09aa712e9c84c056cd7a-15bc8803724197129aea59577cac334736fadd3f.jpg"/>
    <Screenshot url="small_480x320_ce4d635a786e427983c30f1abd8617a1_4d9b74b7f8ffa9ca19d64bee4a9592b9-36a9e665b0546b09e5496a5d02ba5e1bcd0bf563.jpg"/>
    <Screenshot url="small_480x320_3e95d91de62aa2c52e4ff7f32a10a1d9_8a39c9eb9fa2bc2d5f5e789705713e12-a5ec1865bc88c6569af106d9131b45f1f82f8a1b.jpg"/>
    <Screenshot url="small_480x320_3776b5fc7eceed4da9256105889578a3_4265bb97bda45a213357341ddaa81ce9-dae64333deb2cc09f69d0e74e79f4def199caaa2.jpg"/>
</Screenshots>
</App>
```

and i want to parse it and have

```
$Id = "129";
$Path = "category/self";
$Screenshots = array(... screenshots ... all 5 of them);
```

Now ... i have no problem doing this with XSLT for example, but i don't fully understand DOM after reading the documentation. All i have so far is

is this xpath thing http://codepad.org/BtvNEnjl that just read an value between tags and i don't know how to make it to "foreach" it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str); // or use simplexml_load_file()

$id = (string) $xml->Id['id'];
$path = (string) $xml->Path['id'];

$screenshots = array();
foreach($xml->xpath('/App/Screenshots/Screenshot') as $screenshot)
{
    $screenshots[] = (string) $screenshot['url'];
}
```

Comment: are you shure simplexml is a solution? my ex teacher said that i shoud avoid simple xml, and only use dom

Comment: @RowMinds:  The only "issue" regarding SimpleXML that I can think of would be that it yells a lot if the XML isn't perfect.  You should have a look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/simplexml.examples-errors.php) from PHP.net regarding error handling.

Comment: thanks, i hope there will be no big problem using SimpleXML over DOM